# how to create curved triangle using clip path

Tags: css

i'm trying to recreate [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ajEP.png) effect using clip path. I've got to this result using `:before`, but how can I create the rounded corner?

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #0076bf;
  margin-top: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0076bf;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    top: -100px;
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
content
</div>
```

Comment: You'd need to define a `path` with a curve in it...not a `polygon`. - and that's quote complex - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path